# How to install intel_rapl_common?

Tags: linux, module, intel

For a project, I'm trying to install Scaphandre on a Debian virtual machine to try and do some tests with the service

I'm currently at the last step of the [installation](https://hubblo-org.github.io/scaphandre/tutorials/installation.html) but when i try to do `modprobe intel_rapl_common` , I just end up with the error: `"FATAL: Module intel_rapl_common not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-14-amd64`

I tried to find the files to use the intel_rapl module and the only thing I saw was [this](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-trusty-3.18/drivers/powercap/intel_rapl.c) which probably didn't work because it seems to be about android. Considering I have no experience with modules, I have absolutely no idea how to modprobe the intel_rapl_common needed and I am completely stumped on what to do now